# How to do addition of numbers consisted of multiple integers

Tags: c++, integer, overflow, unsigned, carryflag

I am currently working on trying to implement a program that can compute some cryptographic hash functions. I am in the process of making a BigInt class that I hope will allow me to do basic math and logic operations with arbitrarily sized integers.

Part of the class im working on:

```cpp
class BigInt
{
  std::vector<unsigned int> num;
  BigInt operator+ (BigInt num_to_add)
  {
    //Implementation
  }
}
```

What I am hoping is there is some way to add unsigned integers and get the overflow bit, and a way to pass this overflow bit in to the next integer, like you can so in assembly language, I believe that the opcode in ARM Assembly is 'ADCS' which will set the overflow bit and also take to overflow bit and carry it into the next addition sum. However I have searched around and I can't seem to find any functionality for this in the C++ language.

Edit: Just in case anybody stumbles upon this, here is my implementation of the addition function.

```cpp
class big_int
{
    public:
    std::vector<unsigned int> num;
    big_int(std::vector<unsigned int> num)
    {
        this->num = num;
    }
    big_int operator+ (unsigned int num_to_add)
    {
        bool carry_flag = true;
        std::vector<unsigned int> output_num;
        for (unsigned int num_part : num)
        {
            unsigned int value = num_part;
            if(carry_flag)
            {
                value = num_part + num_to_add;
            }
            else
            {
                value = num_part;
            }
            carry_flag = false;
            if (value < num_to_add || value < num_part)
            {
                carry_flag = true;
                num_to_add = 1;
                output_num.push_back(value);
            }
            else
            {
                output_num.push_back(value);
            }
        }
        if (carry_flag)
        {
            output_num.push_back(1);
        }
        big_int out_obj(output_num);
        return out_obj;
    }
    big_int operator+ (big_int num_to_add)
    {
        int smallest_size;
        int largest_size;
        std::vector<unsigned int> largest_num;
        if (num.size() > num_to_add.num.size())
        {
            largest_size = num.size();
            smallest_size = num_to_add.num.size();
            largest_num = num;
        }
        else
        {
            largest_size = num_to_add.num.size();
            smallest_size = num.size();
            largest_num = num_to_add.num;
        }
        bool carry_flag = false;
        std::vector<unsigned int> out_num;
        for(int i = 0; i < smallest_size; i++)
        {
            unsigned int num_a = num[i];
            unsigned int num_b = num_to_add.num[i];
            unsigned int result;
            if (carry_flag)
            {
                result = num_a + num_b + 1;
            }
            else
            {
                result = num_a + num_b;
            }
            carry_flag = false;
            if (result < num_a || result < num_b)
            {
                carry_flag = true;
            }
            out_num.push_back(result);
        }
        std::vector<unsigned int> rest_of_largest_num;
        if (smallest_size == largest_size)
        {
            if (carry_flag)
            {
                out_num.push_back(1);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            for(int i = smallest_size; i < largest_size; i++)
            {
                rest_of_largest_num.push_back(largest_num[i]);
            }
            if (carry_flag)
            {
                big_int rest_of_largest_num_obj(rest_of_largest_num);
                rest_of_largest_num_obj = rest_of_largest_num_obj + 1;
                rest_of_largest_num = rest_of_largest_num_obj.num;
            }
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < rest_of_largest_num.size(); i++)
        {
            out_num.push_back(rest_of_largest_num[i]);
        }
        big_int out_obj(out_num);
        return out_obj;
    }
};
```

Comment: Why not get a pre-existing "BigInt" class, like `boost::multiprecision`?  More precisely, the [cpp_int](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_72_0/libs/multiprecision/doc/html/boost_multiprecision/tut/ints/cpp_int.html) class in that library.

Comment: I don't really like using libraries other than the ones that come with a language, if I was using libraries I could just use the QT one that does cryptographic hashes, but I want to do it myself.

Comment: If adding two `unsigned` values, overflow can be detected if the result of `a+b` gives a result that is less than either `a` or `b`.   That's how unsigned logic (otherwise known as modulo arithmetic) works.   There is no "overflow bit" as such.

Comment: Ahh that's a clever solution, thanks Peter.

Comment: Boost is much more than just another library.  The `boost` library is at this point in the C++ language history, *the* library that is used by professionals to provide the functionality they need that doesn't exist in the standard.  As a matter of fact, it is `boost` that influences the C++ committee very heavily.  Also, the goal of `cpp_int` is arbitrary integer math.  It knows nothing about cryptographic hashes.  You still have to write the code to do the latter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How to do addition of numbers consisted of multiple integers

Remember in school, when you would add numbers like this?

```
       1
  1234567
+  123456
  ......3
```

This is the algorithm that is used with arbitrary precision math. Instead of ranging from 0..9, each term would be the range of `unsigned int` (in your case).

> What I am hoping is there is some way to add unsigned integers and get the overflow bit

There is no way to access overflow bit in C++. Consider that not all CPU's even have such feature.